Completeness and type of theory produced by each geometric construction
So collapsible compass and straightedge allows only solutions to quadratic equations.
The resulting theory is complete
My question is the corresponding type of numbers generated and completeness of the theories for each construction:

Constructions using conic sections(My guess is that given conics are quadratic equations nothing is new here)
Constructions using neusis(this is a different theory given the trisection of angles)
Are there modern constructions in geometry that allow us to get more numbers, for example an algebraically closed field?


Conic sections can get you polynomials of higher degree because you can intersect them; you can get cubics or quartics.

Thanks! @QiaochuYuan . Do you know about the numbers that neusis can get you?
